# Jquery val is not working when try to get a value from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried to insert a form in woocommerce product page. I've inserted the form in the product page. When the form is submitted I'm trying to get the email (form input value) and validate it accordingly.

The problem is I'm not able to get the value in some theme using `jQuery`. I see the form and its elements in firebug. But `jQuery` is not even working for the click event in variable product (woocommerce product page). Here the form is inside their form (which enctype is multipart/form-data), this might be one reason or if I place the form above the variable product form `jQuery` it works but it returns empty string.

Even if there is some text inside the form input field, it returns empty string.

Here is the form

Here is the jQuery On submit click

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.mailsub').click(function() {
     var subaddress = jQuery('.subemail').val();
     console.log(subaddress);
     if ( jQuery('.subemail').length > 0 ){
       console.log('the element with element_id exists in the DOM');
     }
     //ajax goes here followed by validation for the email
     return false;
   });
});
```

I've tried to check whether it is in DOM or not, so I've used the code, it says `the element with element_id exists in the DOM`.

I'm able to get the form completely work on `twentyeleven` and defaults themes. It is working in wordpress defaults themes but not in some other third party themes.

What might be the problem? Any suggestion would be much helpful.

Comment: Why not use ID instead of class? Also please format your code nicely when you post. It is hard to read as it is now

Comment: are you sure jquery is actually loaded in the third party themes?

Comment: @slapthelownote: He/she wouldn't see the `console.log` output if it weren't.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - was just checking because in the question he/she notes:  "But jquery is not even working for the click event in variable product".

Comment: @slapthelownote: Hi Thanks, jquery is loading. Only on particular portion of place it click event is not working. Check my comment in crowder answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML and code as given should mostly work. I'm guessing that there is another element with the class `subemail` earlier in the document. When you do `jQuery(".subemail").val()`, jQuery finds all of the matching elements, but then returns the value (if any) of only the first of them.

---

Side note: If you step through the code with the debugger built into your browser, rather than doing `console.log` statements, you can inspect variables as the code is running, which is *dramatically* more educational, usually.

---

Side note 2: Some browsers submit forms when the user presses Enter in a text field. In that case, the `click` event on the submit button may not be fired (since the button wasn't clicked). To reliably hook into the form submission process, use the `submit` event on the form, rather than the `click` event on the button.

---

Side note 3: You've said you're using ajax to validate the email address. By default, ajax calls are *asynchronous*, which means you cannot use the result from the server to decide whether to submit the form, because you don't get the result until after the submit event handler has returned and (probably) the form has already been submitted. You can make the ajax call synchronous, but that locks up the UI of most browsers while the call is in progress, leading to poor user experience. I suggest validating the email address via ajax when the field changes, and then again on the server when it receives the form (you can never rely on client-side validation). That lets you give the user proactive feedback (the on-change validation) without trying to validate it via ajax when submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks perfect guess +1. As you said it(element) is two time repeated. Where first one is display:none; in the third party theme. Side note 2:Thanks for the info, i'll use it. Side note 3:I didn't do ajax validation, i'm just checking whether it is a valid email address.

Comment: I have one doubt in variable product. Jquery is not working(means only in the particular section as you said to @slapthelownote jquery is loaded) I tried adding a click event with a alert on the input text box, alert working on simple product but not in variable product when i click the input text box which means jquery is not triggering here up to me. variable product has a enctype of multipart/form-data. What might be the problem can you guess anything. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I said jquery is not working isn't? It is due to the `click` function i had. Now i made it to `on click` now it is working. I misunderstand this bug and said it as jquery is not worked:) Let me know if you have anything to say about this.